# How to transform these coordinates by substitution in classical mechanics?

Tags: coordinate-systems

The goal is to transform the following coordinates:
$$x(t)= R(\Phi-\sin\Phi)$$ and
$$z(t)=R(2 +\cos\Phi)$$

with the substitution: $u=\cos\left(\Phi/2\right)$

in order to get:
$$x(t)=2R(\arccos(u)-u\sqrt{1-u^2})$$ and
$$z(t)=R(1+2u^2)$$

How do I go about solving this problem?
I already tried using the following addition theorems: $\cos(\Phi/2)=\sqrt{(1+\cos\Phi)/2)}$ and $\sin\Phi=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\Phi}$
and identities for $\arccos$, but somehow I failed to transform the coordinates.

Comment: Is R(x) a function or a multiplication by constant ?

Comment: What is your source ??? Has anything to do with Brachistochrone - Tautochrone  - Cycloid ???
\begin{equation}
x\left(t\right) = R\Biggl[ \sqrt{\dfrac{\,g\,}{R}}\,t-\sin \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\,g\,}{R}}\,t\right)\Biggr]=R\Bigl[\omega\,t-\sin \left(\omega\,t\right)\Bigr]
\tag{01a}\label{01a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y \left(t\right) = R\Biggl[1-\cos \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\,g\,}{R}}\,t\right)\Biggr]=R\Bigl[1-\cos \left(\omega\,t\right)\Bigr]
\tag{01b}\label{01b}
\end{equation}

Comment: Note that
\begin{equation}
z(t)=R(2 +\cos\Phi)=3R-R(1 -\cos\Phi) 
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation}

Comment: Related : [What is the position as a function of time for a mass falling down a cycloid curve?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/177847/what-is-the-position-as-a-function-of-time-for-a-mass-falling-down-a-cycloid-cur/287749#287749).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is quite straightforward, I'm not sure where you're having a problem. I won't give the full answer since this is a classic "homework-style" problem, I'll just show you how to do one of them, and the other can be done in almost exactly the same way. Take the first equation, you want to go from:

$$x(t) = R(\Phi - \sin\Phi) \quad \quad \text{to} \quad \quad x(t) = R ( 2 \cos^{-1}u - 2u\sqrt{1- u^2}).$$

The most sensible substitution to start with is $$\Phi = 2 \cos^{-1}u \quad \quad \text{or}\quad \quad u = \cos\left({\frac{\Phi}{2}}\right).$$

Draw out a little triangle (or use trigonometric identities), and you should be able to show that this means that $$\sin{\left(\frac{\Phi}{2}\right)} = \sqrt{1-u^2}.$$

Then, using the simple result $$\sin\Phi = 2\sin{\left(\frac{\Phi}{2}\right)}\cos{\left(\frac{\Phi}{2}\right)},$$ you should be done. You should now be able to do the next one, after you find a relation between $\cos\Phi$ and $\cos(\Phi/2)$ and $\sin(\Phi/2)$.

Answer (score 2):

As I always have problems to memorize trigonometric identities, I prefer to start by a basic identity:

$$e^{i\phi}=\left(e^{i\phi/2}\right)^2$$

an use Euler's formula for real and imaginary parts:

$$\cos(\phi)=\left(\cos(\phi/2)\right)^2-\left(\sin(\phi/2)\right)^2$$
$$\sin(\phi)=2\cos(\phi/2)\sin(\phi/2)$$

From these two trigonometric identities and introducing the definition of $u$:
$$\cos(\phi)=u^2-(\sqrt{1-u^2})^2=...$$
$$\sin(\phi)=...$$

you will finish in the target equations.